# Default settings to handle tabs or spaces in source code with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have old code in github which needs modification but whenever I change the code it prompts me for either Tabify or Untabify as the file has mixed tabs and spaces.

I can use the PowerTools to fix those few lines which are different but the problem is when I make changes using either Tabify or Untabify it shows those differences in code review changes as well.

for code reviewers it is really annoying to ignore those changes while doing a code review.

Is there any default settings in VS2017 which all developers can adopt so that everyone is using only either tabs or spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is better way to handle tabs and spaces in visual studio using [Editor config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2019) file `.editorconfig`

You can define either tabs or spaces to be used in specific file extensions using a simple config entry as shown below.

check more formatting details on [editorconfig.org](https://editorconfig.org/)

```
# top-most EditorConfig file
root = true

# Unix-style newlines with a newline ending every file
[*]
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true

# Matches multiple files with brace expansion notation
# Set default charset
[*.{cs,vb}]
charset = utf-8

# 4 space indentation
[*.cs]
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 2

# Tab indentation (no size specified)
[Makefile]
indent_style = tab

# Indentation override for all JS under lib directory
[lib/**.js]
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 2

# Matches the exact files either package.json or .travis.yml
[{package.json,.travis.yml}]
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 2
```